# Symfony - rendering an image

Tags: rendering, symfony

I've got a problem with rendering an image to which a path I gather from database. The path as the string is being gathered without any problem, I can even output in template that path, but when I try to use a construction in template:

```
< img src="{{ asset('path_to_the_image') }}" />
```

or

```
< img src="{{ asset('uploads/photos/name_of_the_file') }}" />
```

I can only see the shape of place in which there should be outputted the image.

```
When I use a construction like:

     {{ path }}

 I can see the path (as a string) to the image.
```

Could you please point me out, where I did a mistake? Thank you

Comment: did you check the permissions? can you watch the file by pudding the path in the browser?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, permission are done as well for the folders as for the file itself, which doesn't change anything - the file cannot be seen. Regarding the path to the file which I can gather from the database - there is no problem with that, I can see the path in the browser. I did not write that earlier but I use Ubuntu OS 16.04

Comment: You are saying "the shape of place" is only shown, but could you see if it is counted as error in browser (red x shown in developer tool pane) or not? If it's error, what does browser say about the image not shown with the tag you constructed? Did you check the HTML source code from the page actually rendered(e.g. in Chrome, right click on the image and choose "inspect")? If you copy the src attribute in the img tag from the actual code and paste it, does that really show the image as you intended?

Comment: Maybe I should have added that I use Symfony the 3.1.2 version. There doesn't seem to by any errors when I look at the developer tool. I took the path of the wanted image as you suggested from the "inspect" property" - right click on the place where the image should be shown and pasted this path into the twig tempate, which didn't change anything. I even did by hand a command: php bin/console asset:install --symflink, still the same.

Comment: What's the difference between keeping the folders such as images and views when the path is ../app/Resources/.. than when the path is /src/AppBundle/Resources/.. ? Because for instance I keep the templates in views folder in this "sort of" path /app/Resources/views/ but images are in /web/bundles/app/images/

Comment: Ok, I have already got to know that keeping the templates and images in the bundle's area is usefull when there is a plan to share the bundl's data with other bundles data, and in other case the folders can be kept outside the bundle.

Comment: I have still got the problem with rendering images in the templates